# In typescript is there a way to access the property of an interface property of type array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, interface

I am writing a code generator to generate typescript based off of a JSON definition of a data structure.
I am having an issue with accessing properties in object arrays within an interface.

Here is an example interface that poses the issue:

```
interface SomeComplexThing {
  propA: string
  propB: number
  propC: {
    propCA: Array<{
      propCA1: string
      propCA2: number
    }>
  }
  propD: SomeComplexThing['propC']['propCA']['propCA1'] // Error: Property 'propCA1' does not exist on type '{ propCA1: string; propCA2: number; }[]'
}
```

When trying to access `SomeComplexThing['propC']['propCA']['propCA1']` I get the error:

```
Property 'propCA1' does not exist on type '{ propCA1: string; propCA2: number; }[]'
```

Now I know that I can access the property using an array index like this:

`SomeComplexThing['propC']['propCA'][0]['propCA1']`

Or even like this:

`SomeComplexThing['propC']['propCA'][1234]['propCA1']`

It seems odd to not be able to access the property inside this array type without having to reference it by some arbitrary number... When generating the code, I don't currently have the context to know that `SomeComplexThing['propC']['propCA']` is an array type, so I can't add `[0]` in there as the type could just be an object.

Is there another way to write this in Typescript, or a Utility function of some kind that I could use to safely access the property without using the array index reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered indexing an array type with a number will get you the item type. The more general approach is to index using the `number` type itself

```
propD: SomeComplexThing['propC']['propCA'][number]['propCA1']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDCWAOANhAB4AqAFqAObIDeAUMsvlOvgIIBcyAzmFBpMWbfACEeIAK6YARtGGt2OHo2bMl+HN2QcoUOAE8APGvUbR2gIw9+gkNWHnN2gEySZ8qE+QBfAHzCvoqiACI8GNh4mESklDQA2gDkLkkAuskuHOkJ0nLQGSmWHFbpyAy+QA)

Note: Indexing with a specific number vs the number type will produce the same result for arrays, but might produce different results for tuples, which do have a different type for each index value. Here indexing by `number` will get a union of all item types in the tuple